# How to edit Sublime text 3 build system for Scheme to allow input from file?

Tags: scheme, sublimetext3

I am using mit-scheme and edit the source file with Sublime Text 3.  In the build system, I set the configuration to be

```
{
    "cmd": ["mit-scheme", "--load", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.scheme"
}
```

but `--load` option does not evaluate the code, that is, it simply loads the code without giving output.  How should I set the configuration option such that when I hit `ctrl+B` it would gives the same output as that when I run `mit-scheme < filename.scm` in the command line?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your question. What does *"it does not evaluate the code"* mean? Does just the input command not work, or does the entire file not run at all? Are there any errors? If so, please add the **full text** to the question. Does the same command with the same file work on the command line? Please [edit] your question with the answers to all of these questions, do not put them in comments.

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks for your suggestion, I have already updated my description.  Feel free to ask if it is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `shell_cmd` in your build system instead of `cmd`, the command will be executed by the shell directly as if you had entered it into a terminal. On Linux, the shell used is `/bin/sh`, while on Windows the shell is taken from the value of the COMSPEC variable (see the Python [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#popen-constructor) help, which is what the `exec` command uses to execute programs).

To use `shell_cmd`, you specify a string instead of an array of strings, and the string is passed directly to the shell to be executed. As such you need to take care to quote any arguments that might have spaces in them.

For example, your build system might look like this:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "mit-scheme < \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.scheme"
}
```

Note that here the `$file` is wrapped in quotes so that if the file has spaces in it, the command still works. Additionally, since the build system is JSON, the quotes need to be quoted (i.e. appear as `\"` and not just `"`).